# TextField - focusing

Tags: flutter

I have two TextFields, I would like that clicking on another widget (Button, Container, Card) won't take away the focus of the TextField that is currently focused. How can I also get information about which text field is currently focused?

```
Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            width: 250,
            child: Column(children: [
              TextField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
              TextField(
                focusNode: _secondFocusNode,
              ),
              Focus(
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        debugPrint('Has Focus: ${_focusNode.hasFocus}');
                        debugPrint(
                            'Has Primary Focus: ${_focusNode.hasPrimaryFocus}');
                      },
                      child: Center(child: Text('Click me!'))))
            ])))
```

Additionally, when I have focus on one of the TextField, I don't know why, but if I click the button, I get:

> - 'Has Focus: false'
> - 'Has Primary Focus: false'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track the current `activeFocuseNode` and use `onTap` to select the value on `TextFiled`, and recall the `FocusNode` again.

```dart
 final List<FocusNode> _focusNodes = List.generate(2, (index) => FocusNode());
  int activeFocuseNode = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 250,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
              autofocus: true,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  activeFocuseNode = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              focusNode: _focusNodes[1],
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  activeFocuseNode = 1;
                });
              },
            ),
            Focus(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  debugPrint('Has Focus: ${_focusNodes[0].hasFocus}');
                  debugPrint(
                      'Has Primary Focus: ${_focusNodes[1].hasPrimaryFocus}');
                  if (activeFocuseNode >= 0) {
                    FocusScope.of(context)
                        .requestFocus(_focusNodes[activeFocuseNode]);
                  }
                },
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Click me!'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```